# DNS packet (response answer and DNS query)

Tags: c, dns, packet-capture, sniffer

I'm coding a program by C language in order to analyze DNS packet.
Specifically, I have to capture DNS packet and I need to know the domain name after capturing DNS packets. How can a access to the answer section?
My code is using pcap library.
Anyone can give me some suggestions? A sample code will be very helpfull for me.
Many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I wish, I had time to make this and help the topic. But here, the [IETF RFC 1035 LINK](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks you, @Kumar!